# jQuery modal pop up disappears when mouse pointer leaves the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a reactjs project in which i have nav menus, and i'm using jquery modal pop up, one of my menus is "Import" which contains two sub menus "CCAWB & GAWB" i'm using react component to render these two submenus under "Import"

```
     <li className="has-submenu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>Import</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul className="submenu">
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <RenderCCAWB_GAWBPopUp submenu ="CCAWB"/>
                                <RenderCCAWB_GAWBPopUp submenu ="GAWB"/>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </li>
```

RenderCCAWB_GAWBPopUp Component returns the following

```
 render(){
        return(<li onClick={this.handleShowModal}>
                 {this.props.submenu}
                 {this.state.view.showModal ? <UpdateQualityHeaderDummy 
   handleHideModal={this.handleHideModal} menuName={this.props.submenu} />:null}
               </li>);}
```

on click of any of the sub menus "CCAWB/GAWB" i want to show the modal pop up 
which's returned by another component

UpdateQualityHeaderDummy returns the modal itself

```
 return (
               <div className="modal" data-backdrop='static' id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div className="modal-dialog" >
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{title}</h5>
                      <button onClick={this.closePop} type="button" className="close" 
                          data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body">
                                    <div  className="row">
                                        <div className=" col-lg-12 col-xl-12 
                                                          qcUpdateStatus">    
                                        </div>                           
                                           <FileUpload menuTitle={this.props.menuName}/>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick ={this.closePop}>Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick ={this.downloadFeed}>Download Feed</button>     
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.validateForm}> Upload </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>);
            } });
```

till here everything works fine and the modal shows up as attached bellow
[Screen 1 for the scenario ][1]

*= > the problem is here, whenever the mouse pointer leaves the browser (i.e goes to the url bar) the modal and the sub menus disappear but the modal opacity stays there (attached bellow)

[Screen 2 when the pointer is outside the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CSyK.png)

*= >but they show up immediately as soon as the pointer is back to the page (any where)
attached bellow screen 3
[Screen 3 when the pointer is inside the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FEpJ.png)

*=> my trials: i have tried the event mouseleave(when mouse leaves the browser) and set the visibility of the sub menus as visible but they keep disappearing i even set the modal show property as true in the same event but also doesn't work.

```
 $(document).mouseleave(function () {
                    $('.modal').css('visibility','visible');
                    $('#navigation > div > ul > li:nth-child(5) > 
                      ul').css('visibility','visible');

                    $('#myModal > div').css('visibility','visible');
                    $('#myModal > div > div').css('visibility','visible');});
```

any suggestions please ?